# How to say "become" in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I can think of at least two different words for "to become" in Spanish. They are "hacerse" and "ponerse."

What's the difference? My understanding is "hacerse" is to become in an ACTIVE way. The original context was the title, Mr. Lucky goes (becomes) Latin. My translation would be Senor Lucky se hace Latino.

On the other hand, ice becomes water above 0 degrees C. El hielo se pone el agua sobre la temperatura de 0 grado C. That's because it is more of a "passive" becoming.

Are these uses right or am I missing something?

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/136/45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ice becomes water above 0 degrees C.

```
El hielo (se) licúa a más de cero grados. 
El hielo (se) licúa por encima de cero grados.
El hielo a más de cero grados se licúa.
El hielo por encima de cero grados se licúa.
```

(Las oraciones todas sin comas, aunque hay una pequeña pausa detrás de hielo la coma no tiene lugar)
Estas traducciones se adaptan más a la forma más recomendable de hablar en español, donde el uso de hacer y convertirse, si pueden ser sustituidos por un verbo más exacto debiera hacerse.

Mr. Lucky becomes Latin. Aunque no estoy seguro, parece ser algo relacionado con alguna canción del autor de la música de La Pantera Rosa, **Henry Mancini**. (Por desgracia el contexto en este caso, no es contexto, es solo una frase y limita mucho para hacer una traducción apropiada)

Si asi fuera ya Mr Lucky bien pudiera pasar a ser Señor Suerte, Señor Afortunado o alguna cosa parecida.

Si fuera que la canción Mr Lucky es interpretada al estilo latino, pues así mismo sería la traducción: Mr Lucky al estilo latino. Aquí la traducción de becomes difícilmente aparezca en algún diccionario (Aunque puede haber sorpresas) Pero sin dudas sería la traducción correcta.

Por otra parte en español (creo que en inglés tambien) algo puede convertirse en otra cosa material o metafóricamente. No es lo mismo convertirse, por ejemplo, en canadiense que convertirse en latino. La nacionalidad canadiense existe y es algo en lo cual uno se puede "convertir" que en cualquier caso no sería una traducción correcta decir fulano se convirtió en canadiense o fulano se hizo canadiense. Hay algunas variantes para decirlo, sin duda, mucho mejor.

Pero materialmente nadie puede convertirse en latino porque no existe "latinlandia" y no existe forma de que te den un pasaporte latino y de pronto. ZAZ!! Te conviertas en latino.
Mucho más fácil es convertirse en estatua de sal que convertirse en latino. En cualquier caso si hablamos de una persona que  podría adoptar las normas y costumbres y vivir como un latino. Pero en nuestra lengua no podemos (no debemos) decir que se ha hecho latino. Podríamos decir, por ejemplo: Esta hecho todo un latino! Pero jamás se hace latino.

He visto incluso decir **Shakira **becomes latin*** diva*, aqui se convierte en diva latina. Que no es lo mismo ni parecido a convertirse en latina.

Otro ejemplo: Calle 54' **becomes Latin** jazz mecca in Madrid, aqui nadie se convierte latino, es madrid la que se convierte en la meca del jazz latino.

**becomes Latin lover** se convierte en amante latino, otra vez no se convierte en latino sino en latin lover.

En conclusión una persona no puede convertirse en latina, puede simular ser o aparentar ser latina. Sin embargo si el latino tiene un apellido detrás (lease diva, bailarina o convertiría en latina sino en diva latina, bailarina latina o cantante latina. Pero es imposible convertirse en latino. ya no es una cuestion de idiomas o traducción ppráctica y de lógica.

Por otra parte becomes si parece servir para decir que alguien toma la apariencia de algo:
intr)
    1. (copula) to come to be; develop or grow into he became a monster
    2. (foll by of; usually used in a question) to fall to or be the lot (of); happen (to) what became of him?
    **3. (tr) (of clothes, etc.) to enhance the appearance of (someone); suit that dress becomes you**
    4. (tr) to be appropriate; befit it ill becomes you to complain
    [Old English becuman to happen; related to Old High German biqueman to come to, Gothic biquiman to appear suddenly]
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/becomes

Tambien he leído que un cantante se transformó en latino por 10 minutos (En caso de un cantante no latino cantando al estilo latino) En este caso hay una transformación momentánea, figurada, y esa tranformación temporal en español no significa que se convierta en latino sino que adopta la forma de un latino.

Si tomamos en cuenta todo lo anterior y si Mr lucky no fuera una canción, sino una persona podriamos decir entonces que Mr Lucky esta haciéndose pasar por latino, o está fingiendo ser latino. Y si se quiere utilizar el verbo hacer:

> **Mr Lucky está hecho todo un latino.**
>
> **Mr Lucky se latiniza.**

Answer (score 7):

*Volverse* o *convertirse en* are the best translations I can think of, but *se hace* works in some situations too:

- Ice becomes water above 0 degrees C: El hielo se convierte en agua por encima de los 0 grados C.
- Mr. Lucky becomes Latin: Mr. Lucky se hace latino.

Comment: ¿Mr Lucky se hace latino? Finje ser latino, o se hace pasar por latino

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: No, "se hace" no significa necesariamente "se hace pasar por". Puede significar "se convierte en", como aquí.

Comment: pero no creo que nadie pueda convertirse en latino. Al menos en la epoca actual. Ni en la edad antigua tampoco. Aqui no aplica convertirse en. Y se hace tampoco procede. En español no se suele hablar asi. En realidad en todo caso si no es latino finge serlo o se hace pasar por. Al traducir hay que ver el contexto, con un poco de imaginacion. Sino traductore traidore.

Comment: Hasta pudiera aceptarse se hace el latino.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: "se hace latino" y "se hace el latino" significan cosas muy distintas. La primera se interpreta (al menos en España) como "becomes"; la segunda como "pretends to be".

Comment: tercera acepción http://www.thefreedictionary.com/becomes

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: Creo que estás "missing the point". :-)

Comment: No, nadie puede hacerse latino, Tu ponme un ejemplo de alguien que conoces que se convirtió en latino y tendrás toda la razón. De cualquier modo debajo está mi respuesta. No es cuestión de idioma ni de traducción es una cuestión práctica y de sentido común.

Answer (score 5):

"Él se convirtió en latino" me suena mejor.

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Otra palabra que se usa en literatura significativamente es [devenir](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=devenir).
Espero sirva de algo.

Another word that is used in literature is [devenir](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=devenir).
I hope it is still helpful.

Comment: Ciertamente de alguna forma pudiera usarse tambien el verbo devenir.

Answer (score 2):

Become can also be translated into "llegar a ser", "convertirse en" for your translations

Mr. Lucky becomes Latin  - Senor Lucky se hace Latino.
you really want to translate it with other verb
like 
Mr. Lucky becomes Latin  - El Señor Lucky se convierte en una persona Latina.

If you see I am adding more stuff in spanish, so your english idea is complemented, the issue here is that in English you are straight forward, but in spanish there are several ways to say the same idea, sometimes with double sense.

On the other hand
ice becomes water above 0 degrees C - El hielo se pone el agua sobre la temperatura de 0 grado C.

ice becomes water above 0 degrees C - El hielo se hace agua o se convierte en agua ....

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you find that "Mr. Lucky becomes Latin" title? It makes no sense. The only reference I know is, as @Ernesto Marrero says, Henry Mancini's soundtrack to the Mr. Lucky's series.

There's a version by Mancini called "Mr. Lucky (goes Latin)" and a good translation would be "Mr. Lucky a lo latino".

The "Mr Lucky al estilo latino" that Ernesto proposes could be the translation of "Mr. Lucky (Latin style)".